# i need different logo to about page and other pages in php?

Tags: php, codeigniter

i tried to implement the logo differentiate like this , please find out an issue , Thank you
how can i change the logo differentiate so far

```
@if($title == 'About' ){
    <img src = "files/images/logo_wta_white.png" srcset = "files/images/logo_wta_white.png 1x, files/images/logo_wta_white@2x.png 2x" alt = "logo_wta_white">
@else
    <img src = "files/images/logo_wta.png" srcset = "files/images/logo_wta.png 1x, files/images/logo_wta@2x.png 2x" alt = "logo_wta">
@endif
```

Comment: Where is "$title" variable defined?And with which value?

Comment: which framework you are using?

Comment: You can do it by using url comparision.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For core php

```
if(basename($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']) == "about.php"){ /* basename($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']) Returns The Current PHP File Name */
<img src = "files/images/logo_wta_white.png" srcset = "files/images/logo_wta_white.png 1x, files/images/logo_wta_white@2x.png 2x" alt = "logo_wta_white">
}else{
<img src = "files/images/logo_wta.png" srcset = "files/images/logo_wta.png 1x, files/images/logo_wta@2x.png 2x" alt = "logo_wta">
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
if(strcmp($title ,"About") ==0)
{?>
<img src="files/images/logo_wta_white.png" 
srcset ="files/images/logo_wta_white.png 1x, 
files /images/logo_wta_white@2x.png 2x" 
alt ="logo_wta_white">
<?php
} else {
?>
<img src="files/images/logo_wta.png" 
srcset ="files/images/logo_wta.png 1x, 
files /images/logo_wta@2x.png 2x" alt="logo_wta">
<?php
}
?>
```